# C++: List elements disappearing from container

Tags: c++, list, stl, containers

I'm calling a function to read some data from two files and insert it in an instance of class Corso. The class consists of a list of Alumni, each of which has a list of Exams that has to be populated, this is what leggiEsame() accomplishes. The first call to leggiEsame() adds the data correctly. The second call, though, appears to add the Exams to the previous, but at some point the new data disappears. I'm calling the functions from main:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Corso.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Corso c = Corso();
    c.leggiEsame("informatica.txt", Esame(1, "Informatica", "Danilo Franchini", 31, 18, 0, 10));
    c.leggiEsame("analisi.txt", Esame(2, "Analisi", "Marco Giovannetti", 31, 18, 0, 10));
    c.stampa();
    return 0;
}
```

leggiEsame() is implemented as so:

```
void Corso::leggiEsame(string path, Esame e)
{
FILE *f = fopen(path.c_str(), "r");
if(f==NULL)
    printf("File non valido.\n");

CodPersona cod_p;
NumMatricola num_m;
char str_voto[20];
float voto;
Alunno al = Alunno();

while(!feof(f))
{
    char format[100] = "%[^\t]\t%[^\t]\t%[^\t]%*[^\n]\n";
    fscanf(f, format, cod_p, num_m, str_voto);

    if(string(str_voto)=="RIMANDATO")
        voto = RIMANDATO;
    else if(string(str_voto)=="30 e Lode")
        voto = LODE;
    else if(string(str_voto)=="ASSENTE")
        voto = ASSENTE;
    else
        voto = atof(str_voto);

    e.setVoto(voto);

    al.setCodPersona(string(cod_p));
    al.setNumMatricola(string(num_m));
    aggiornaAlunno(al, e);
    /*Alunno a = *cercaAlunno(al);
    printf("Alunno %s aggiornato, ha %d esami\n", a.numMatricola().c_str(), a.esami().size());*/
}

fclose(f);
}
```

aggiornaAlunno() does the following:

```
void Corso::aggiornaAlunno(Alunno a, Esame e)
{
Alunno a_found;
list<Alunno>::iterator it = cercaAlunno(a);
/// cerco l'alunno nella classe, se è già presente (iteratore diverso da m_alunni.end())
/// se l'alunno esiste già allora aggiorna i dati anagrafici dell'alunno
/// altrimenti aggiunge l'alunno alla classe.
if(it!=m_alunni.end())
{
    a_found = *it;
    a_found.aggiornaDati(a);
    /// se l'alunno già esistente non contiene l'esame allora lo aggiunge
    if(!a_found.contieneEsame(e, 0))
    {
        a_found.aggiungiEsame(e);
        printf("Aggiunto esame %d su %d a %s\n", e.id(), a_found.esami().size(), a_found.numMatricola().c_str());
    }
}
else
{
    printf("nuovo alunno\n");
    a.aggiungiEsame(e);
    aggiungiAlunno(a);
}
}
```

The "else" branch of the condition seems to work fine, since it adds the data from the first reading, while the second one calls aggiungiEsame():

```
void Alunno::aggiungiEsame(Esame e)
{
m_esami.push_front(e);
printf("Aggiunto esame %d a %s, n esami: %d\n", e.id(), m_num_matricola.c_str(), m_esami.size());
}
```

Inside this function the output is ok, it seems as if new data has been added to each Exams list, since the size outputs 2, and also inside aggiornaAlunno().
It is when the function returns to leggiEsame() that the size of the list outputs 1 again, even though no deletions have been made.
I hope you can help, thanks in advance.

Comment: TLDR; consider *reducing* the code to a *minimal* example.

Comment: Pass container by value vs. pass by reference ?

Comment: Why does `void f(int x) {x += 2;}` ... `int y = 3; f(y); cout << y;` not print 5? Did the +2 get lost somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not adding data to your existing `Alunno` object, you are adding it to *a copy* of your object.  `a_found = *it` copies the contents of `*it` into `a_found`, but they're separate objects.  As soon as `a_found` goes out of scope, it gets destroyed, along with anything you added to it.